# Slim 3 framework: mysql instance good practice

Tags: php, mysql, dependency-injection, slim

I try to figure out what can be the best practice to use an instance of a mysql connection via dependency injection in Slim Framework 3.

I use Rob Allen’s skeleton and added those lines in app/dependencies.php

```php
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c['settings']['LOCAL_DB'];
    return new \App\Action\DatabaseAction($settings['DB_HOST'],$settings['DB_DATABASE'],$settings['DB_USERNAME'],$settings['DB_PASSWORD']); 
};


$container['App\Action\HelloAction'] = function ($c) {
    return new App\Action\HelloAction($c['view'], $c['db']);
};
```

And then use it in the class like this:

```
$data['test'] = $this->db->one('SELECT * FROM database');
```

It's working well, but I can't be sure this is the good way in term of good practices, used resources, memory...

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure it is good. You only instantiate that class when you need it (lazy load) and don't have redundant code.

Comment: Thanks! I've just started using slim and wasn't sure if I understood correctly dependency injection.

Comment: DI means an object gets all dependencies it needs.

Comment: What is this->db->ONE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an excellent way to do it as it follows good dependency injection practices.

In terms of memory usage, you are also ensuring the the database is only instantiated if it's required and not on every request which is also good.

Note that the class that creates the database shouldn't be called `DatabaseAction` though as it's not an action, it's a database instance creator. I would call it something like `App\Database`